# Increment dictionary value in JSON document using Python : Azure functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Currently developing an python backend API that will increment a value in COSMOS DB(azure serverless database) that is currently running NOSQL. Permissions(output/input) bindings is correct. However I'm able to update the cosmos NOSQL document staticky like this:
`

```
import azure.functions as func
import json
import logging

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputDocument: func.DocumentList,  outputDocument: func.Out[func.DocumentList]) ->str:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.route_params.get('name')
    for name in inputDocument:
        logging.info(name.to_json())

    if name:
        newdocs = func.DocumentList()
        visitors = {"id": "VISITOR", "testpartitionkey": "testpartitionkey", "visitor": 12}
        key = "visitor"
        if key in visitors:
            visitors[key] +=1
        newdocs_load_json= json.dumps(visitors)
        newdocs.append(func.Document.from_json(newdocs_load_json))
        outputDocument.set(newdocs)

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, new value is: {name} {newdocs} {newdocs_load_json} . ....")
```

`
Document is retrieved from a different function reading the specific document, I'm only getting as far as incrementing the correct document only once, but as Python code is static, I need to somewhat fetch the value of the ID and Partitionkey[API response that states correct value from Cosmos DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3qYN.png).

After I change python code to following, I'm just getting a default error 500 message. I have been struggeling with this one for a long time, and can't find another way around to increment a value in a JSON document.

Python code I'm trying with:

```
import azure.functions as func
import json
import logging

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputDocument: func.DocumentList,  outputDocument: func.Out[func.DocumentList]) ->str:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.route_params.get('name')
    for name in inputDocument:
        logging.info(name.to_json())

    if name:
        newdocs = func.DocumentList()
        for user in inputDocument:
            user_json = {
               "id": "VISITOR",
               "testpartitionkey": "testpartitionkey",
               "visitor": user['visitor']
              }
            key = "visitor"
        if key in user_json:
            user_json[key] +=1
        newdocs_load_json= json.dumps(user_json)
        newdocs.append(func.Document.from_json(newdocs_load_json))
        outputDocument.set(newdocs)

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, new value is: {name} {newdocs} {newdocs_load_json} . ....")
```

When checking logs in Azure function, this is what's it stating, it's not able to find the key I would like to update cannot be found[error message received in azure functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrPsa.png)

Any ideas how to approach this?

I did change in the code as it stated below here, but not sure if I'm approaching this correct. In short terms I'm expecting this to update an document in a nosql db.

Comment: The exception image you pasted shows there is a typo error in your init. instead of user.to_json(), your code is having `user.to.json()`, correct it and try.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Inedeed I tried to change from to.json to to_json. However that is not the root cause of this problem.

I vchanged that, but just another error occurrs: 
Result: Failure Exception: KeyError: 'visitor' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 458, in